# Error "cannot read property 'setFilter' of undefined" with mapbox js 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, mapbox

El código a continuación captura cuando el usuario hace zoom sobre el mapa, cuando llega a 13 debería esconder la capa `privLayer` pero no reconoce la función que filtra los resultados.

Ya probé con

```
privLayer.setFilter(function() { 
return true; 
}).addTo(map);
```

y por alguna razón no muestra nada, es como si omitiera la función.

```
var map = render_map();
var privLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
.addTo(map);

map.on('zoomend', function() {
    // here's where you decided what zoom levels the layer should and should
    // not be available for: use javascript comparisons like < and > if
    // you want something other than just one zoom level, like
    // (map.getZoom > 10)
    if (map.getZoom() > 13) {

        // setFilter is available on L.mapbox.featureLayers only. Here
        // we're hiding and showing the default marker layer that's attached
        // to the map - change the reference if you want to hide or show a
        // different featureLayer.
        // If you want to hide or show a different kind of layer, you can use
        // similar methods like .setOpacity(0) and .setOpacity(1)
        // to hide or show it.
        map.privLayer.setFilter(function() { 
            return false;});
        console.log('Zoom > 13');
    } else {
        console.log('Zoom < 13');
        map.privLayer.setFilter(function() { return true; });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola Juan, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio). Recuerda que el idioma del sitio es el español. Además deberías explicar mejor el problema, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque son más difíciles de entender. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: traduce el título de tu pregunta